# ExtJS: How to hide specific data on store with filtering?

Tags: filter, extjs, load, store

I want to hide a record on Grid that returns from server.

I've setted a `filter` on store and can reach that specific data but how I'll handle to hide/ignore this record?

```
fooStore: {
    ....
    filters: [
         function(item) {
         let me = this;
         let theRecord = item.data.status === MyApp.STATUS; //true

         if (theRecord) {
              console.log(theRecord); //True
              console.log("So filter is here!!")
              //How to hide/ignore/avoid to load this specific data record to load Grid??
            }
         }
    ]
},
```

Returned JSON;

```
{
  "success": true,
  "msg": "OK",
  "count": 3,
  "data": [
    { 
      //Filter achives to this record and aim to hide this one; avoid to load this record.
      "id": 102913410,
      "status": "P"
    },
    {
      "id": 98713410,
      "status": "I"
    },
    { 
      "id": 563423410,
      "status": "A"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't save my fiddle cause i don't have sencha forum's account so i give you my code :

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var model = Ext.create('Ext.data.Model', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
                {name: 'id',  type: 'int'},
                {name: 'status', type: 'string'},
            ]
        });

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
             autoLoad: true,
             model: model,
             proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url:  'data.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            },
            filters: [function(item) {
                if (item.data.status === "P") {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }],
            listeners: {
                load: {
                    fn: function() {
                        console.log(this.getRange());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Also i create data.json like this :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "msg": "OK",
    "count": 3,
    "data": [{
        "id": 102913410,
        "status": "P"
    }, {
        "id": 98713410,
        "status": "I"
    }, {
        "id": 563423410,
        "status": "A"
    }]
}
```

I thinks it's near to you'r code and after the loading of the store the filter work as you can this :

[image]

Here is sencha fiddle link : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor

If this can't work, i don't understand what the fuck doing...

Comment: Strange... which version of Extjs do you use ?

Comment: version of ExtJS is `6.5.0`

Comment: I'm sorry but still it's not works as expected but maybe there is some implementation error made by me. Let me check on this. And thanks for your effort.

Comment: So fiddle is below; I've refactor only `if only` `true false` part and it's working as expected but somehow when I implement to my project, still loads false setted record instead of ignoring... =( 
@ https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jj5

Comment: worked perfectly.. I made mistake about function! I've set `filters` within `beforeload` instead of `load`. Well, I thought it'll be much better to state on `beforeload` but it should be in `load`! Thanks a lot.

Comment: this will filter the store perfectly but i'm using the store for combo box drop down list and i need to filter the store based on the value in another field in the same form. Is there any way to check that condition too.

Comment: You want to filter your store from a form field wich are not in the store's model ?